# svn merge --dry-run Show svn diff

Tags: svn, merge, diff

I'm working with a codebase that has (historically) been merged by hand rather than via `svn merge`.  I'm trying to change that by proving to everyone how useful merge is - but when I do a dry run, I get this:

```
$ svn merge [[Repo URL]] . -c 21355,21358,21364,21370,21371,21373 --dry-run
--- Merging r21355 into '.':
U    [[File 1]]
--- Merging r21355 into '[[dir]]':
U    [[dir]]/[[File 2]]
U    [[dir]]/[[File 3]]
--- Merging r21358 into '[[dir]]':
U    [[dir]]/[[File 4]]
--- Merging r21364 into '[[dir]]':
U    [[dir]]/[[File 2]]
C    [[dir]]/[[File 4]]    
--- Merging r21370 into '[[dir]]':
U    [[dir]]/[[File 5]]
--- Merging r21371 into '[[dir]]':
U    [[dir]]/[[File 5]]
--- Merging r21373 into '[[dir]]':
C    [[dir]]/[[File 5]]
U    [[dir]]/[[File 6]]
Summary of conflicts:
  Text conflicts: 2
```

I have two files (listed as 4 and 5, respectively), that survive one merge only to pop a conflict with the last one.  I'm trying to figure out what that conflict is now, and see if I can resolve it.  I'd like it if I can force svn to spit out the diff of the two conflicted changes.

I checked out a new working copy of just the narrowest directory, and when I ran the merge without dry run, I got:

```
--- Merging r21355 into '.':
U    [[File 3]]
--- Merging r21358 into '.':
U    [[File 4]]
--- Merging r21364 into '.':
G    [[File 4]]
--- Merging r21370 into '.':
U    [[File 5]]
--- Merging r21371 into '.':
G    [[File 5]]
--- Merging r21373 into '.':
G    [[File 5]]
```

(Files 1, 2, and 6 reside elsewhere)

So, now I'm especially confused - dry run reports a conflict, but when the merge is actually run, it's successful?  Is this intended behaviour?  I'll admit I'm no SVN wizard, but I'm left quite bewildered.

Comment: I can reproduce this problem with two revisions. Rev 7 adds a file and rev 8 changes the file. The commands `svn merge -r6:8` and `svn merge -c7,8` produce the same result. However, if I add the option `--dry-run`, the former succeeds and the latter fails. Sounds like a bug in SVN 1.7.

Comment: @nosid I'm running 1.6.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is expected behavior for `--dry-run`, which does not modify the filesystem.

Because you specified individual revisions, those revisions are being applied separately, one after another.  The `G` in the merge output means that a merge occured - svn made a change to a file that already had a local change.

In detail:

- r21358 modifies File 4.
- In a normal merge, File 4 now has local changes and r21364 merges those changes together because the diff matches the current state of the file.
- In a dry-run, File 4 was not changed by r21358.  The file does not match what the next revision, r21364, expects it to be, so you get a conflict instead.
- The same things happens with r21373 - either r21370 or r21371 modified the same part of the file that it applies to.
- r21371 does not suffer from this because it affects a different part of File 5 than r21370.

Once you're past all these hiccups, you'll be able to merge all of these in one go, without having to specify individual revisions, and this difference between dry-run and a regular merge will just go away.

Comment: I think this what's technically happening, but I think it's a bug, rather than expected behaviour. [This issue](http://subversion.tigris.org/issues/show_bug.cgi?id=2584), marked as fixed with respect to deleted and re-added files, seems to indicate that `merge --dry-run` should function EXACTLY as `merge`, just without changing any files.  `--dry-run` should be a tool that allows you to check these issues before you encounter them.