# Is there a way to see the reason for a tree conflict when running svn merge --dry-run?

Tags: svn, merge, command-line-arguments, tree-conflict

When I do a merge in SVN, I often like to run it with the --dry-run option first so I can see my conflicts, take a look at them, and devise a plan for resolving them as I'm doing my actual merge. This works great for file conflicts, but with tree conflicts, I can't seem to find the extra information about them e.g. local delete, incoming edit upon update.

Is there a way I can get this information through dry run? or without actually having to pollute my local copy with a bunch of conflicts? I don't want to check out another local copy to test the merge because it takes a very long time.

Answer (score 0):

Chris

In tortoise svn client there is an option of Test merge. If you click on that button will provide a list of possible merge conflicts.

The Button is Named  "Test merge".

hope this helps

Comment: I don't use tortoise. I need to be able to do this from the command line.

Comment: Then you need to write a Custom hook script in python or other language to do it for you. More Info [link] http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn-book.html

Comment: Not sure if you tried this , found this link  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16527916/svn-merge-dry-run-show-svn-diff

Answer (score 0):

Some simple work arround without checking out another local copy:

- Save your own changes locally as a patch file with 
  `svn diff > my_changes.patch`
- do the merge

Then if you want to roll back:

- `svn revert -R .` will get you in sync again with the repository.
- `patch < my_changes.patch` will replay all your uncommited changes.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score -1):

The [recommended way](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.6/svn.branchmerge.basicmerging.html#svn.branchmerge.basicmerging.mergeinfo) to review the merge details is to check-in your changes to a branch, then merge to see the changes in your working directory. If you don't want the merge, you just revert at that point.